# Sonata | Symfony 3 | Configure routes in function of user roles

Tags: routes, roles, symfony, user-roles, sonata

I try to configure routes in function of the user roles. This is what I did :

The service :

```
admin.group:
        ...
        calls:
            - [ setTokenStorage, [ "@security.token_storage" ] ]
```

The Admin class :

```
public function setTokenStorage (TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage) {
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;

    $this->user = null;
    $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
    if (null !== $token && is_object($token->getUser())) {
        $this->user = $token->getUser();
    }
}

protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
{
    if ($this->user && $this->user->hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) {
        $collection->remove('delete');
    }
    else {
        $collection->clearExcept(array('list'));
    }
}
```

I get a crash :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "sonata_group_edit" as such route does not exist.") in SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_list_field.html.twig at line 23.
```

It seems that we pass two times in configureRoutes, the first time the user is null, the second time the user is not null. The second time $this->user->hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') is true but it creates this crash.

I'm not using SonataUserBundle because it is not available for Symfony 3.

How can I do it ? TY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I thought Sonata Security would not do the work but it does !

I created specific roles :

```
    ROLE_THEME_VIEWER:
        - ROLE_ADMIN_THEME_LIST
    ROLE_GROUP_VIEWER:
        - ROLE_ADMIN_GROUP_LIST
    ROLE_RULES_VIEWER:
        - ROLE_ADMIN_RULES_LIST
```

And :

```
    ROLE_ADMIN:       [..., ROLE_THEME_VIEWER, ROLE_GROUP_VIEWER, ROLE_RULES_VIEWER]
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html

If you still want to use "configureRoutes" for checking access, you should read this :

https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/issues/2590

This is not a good idea as pulzarraider said. To make my code works, you have to clear the cache every time. That's really bad !